# What SEDE examples would be most useful to new users?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, documentation

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239630/162102) asks about an SEDE tutorial, which doesn't really exist.  The answer there suggests that you can look at existing queries, which I think is how most SEDE users have learned, but that has a couple challenges:

- There are a lot of queries out there.
- Some of them might not be good examples (expensive, unnecessarily cumbersome, obscurely clever, fragile).

So it would be nice to have a small number of [good examples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222544/162102), ones that are models we want people to emulate and that are comprehensible to SEDE beginners.  This would be a nice supplement to the [schema documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/162102).

So my question: if we wanted to pick, or write, a small number (half a dozen?) of good solid examples to use in an SEDE tutorial, which ones should they be?  Please propose (or specify) candidates or, better yet, sets of candidates that *together* would teach people to get the data they want and not tear out too much hair or pound SE's servers mercilessly.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer) is quite old, but some of the queries might still be what you're looking for.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for that pointer!  Looks like there are some interesting queries there; whether they're also good examples I can't say.

Comment: I have answered some like [this one on rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234720/custom-query-data-explorer-rep/234749#234749), [this one on close vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224915/find-questions-where-i-had-the-final-close-vote/234057#234057) and [this one on top users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231408/query-for-top-users-rep-over-the-past-n-days/232082#232082) but they might need some rework to be used as an example.

Comment: Others sources: Here is a Community Wiki FAQ titled: "[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/282094)" which lists all the commands, some examples titled: "[Interesting queries on Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49943/282094)". A [T-SQL Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/t_sql/), Wikipedia's webpage [Transact-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL), and Microsoft's [Transact-SQL Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically I would go with the tools to be able to do stuff yourself first (how to see what the contents of each field in a table are, how to figure out stuff like 'PostTypes' that are numbers), then doing simple WHERE statements (find all questions in the past month), then a simple JOIN (users and posts, for instance)

1. How to determine the contents of a table
2. How to determine the meaning of numerical fields
3. Simple WHERE statements on a single table
4. JOIN statement between two tables
5. Data.SE specific quirks (`[Post Link]`, `##Variable##`)
6. Possibly more complex stuff (sub-queries, `CASE` clauses, `IIF` clauses)

#### Start with the basics

Explain the general layout -- title field, description field, query field, and the table list to the right. Then teach how to run a simple query to look at what's in one of the tables:

```sql
-- SELECT * grabs everything FROM the specified table
-- Since that's a lot of info, we limit it to 100 entries
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM Posts
-- This tells you what fields are in the table with sample data
```

#### Teach about numerical fields

```sql
-- Run this query, what does PostTypeId mean? It's a number!
SELECT Top 100 Title, Id, PostTypeId
FROM Posts
ORDER BY Id DESC
-- Now comment the above lines with --
-- And uncomment the lines below and run again
-- SELECT DISTINCT p.PostTypeId, pt.Name
-- FROM Posts p
-- JOIN PostTypes pt ON p.PostTypeId = pt.Id
-- ORDER BY p.PostTypeId ASC

-- This can be seen much easier if you click on the ? icon
-- next to the PostTypes table in the right hand table list
```

#### Simple `WHERE` statements

```sql
-- What if we only want to see certain posts?
-- For instance, what about all posts in July 2014?
SELECT Title, Id, PostTypeId
FROM Posts
WHERE CreationDate BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-07-31'
-- But some posts have no titles? Why is that? Check PostTypeId
-- Not all items have all data types -- answers don't have titles
-- Uncomment the next line to filter the data to only show questions
--   AND PostTypeId = 1
```

#### JOIN Statements

```sql
-- But what if we want to look only at questions in july by users with <500 rep?
-- We can use a JOIN clause to look at data from two tables
-- But we have to tell the query how to link the tables
SELECT p.Title, p.Id, u.DisplayName, u.Reputation
-- We are using prefixes to explain which table to take info from
FROM Posts p 
-- We are naming Posts 'p' so if two fields have the same name we can differentiate
JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
-- We want to give the info for the user who owns the post on the same line
WHERE p.CreationDate BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-07-31'
  AND p.PostTypeId = 1
-- If we changed this to 'u.CreationDate' what do you think happens?
-- Try it and find out!
```

#### Data.SE Specific Quirks

Not writing examples for these, but teach about `[Post Link]`, `[User Link]`, `##Variables##` and `##UserId##` at the very least.

#### More complex stuff?

Conditional clauses (`CASE`, `IIF`), aggregate clauses (`SUM`, `COUNT`), sub-queries (`WITH tableA AS`), etc. can also be covered for more complex queries, but the above probably handles 70% of most basic queries.

Comment: Hmm, I think I forgot to mention the helper table view (the `?`) on [the help page](http://data.stackexchange.com/help), that might be good to add there too.

Comment: @TimStone, yeah, the help tends to be a bit spartan. Perhaps if folks help flesh out this idea for ways to get started, we can find a way to incorporate it in to your stellar (if not stellarly documented) tool?

Comment: Aye. I tried to be fairly comprehensive on the features when I redid the help page, but it'd be great if we could supplant the fairly basic "Getting Started" section with a more in-depth guide that would be more accommodating to people brand new to SEDE. (And, to give credit where it's due, Data Explorer is [Sam's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/17174/waffles) baby, I'm just the new nanny of sorts)